# Is there a way to make a Button perform multiple commands

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm doing a school project. I designed a welcome page for it on tkinter and put a button 'ok' which when pressed moves the code forward but the welcome page doesnt close itself once pressed.

i have tried defining another function to close it but that does not work.

```
welcome = Tk()
okbutton = Button(welcome, text='ok', command=R)
okbutton.pack()
welcome.mainloop()
```

and the code moves forward but welcome page remains open...Is there a method to resolve this?

Comment: Can you post your whole code? It'll help us help you faster :)

Comment: It is actually a project so the whole code is about 900 lines...i'll leave the github link here https://github.com/RohanSreelesh/School_Project_CRM/blob/master/CUSTOMER_MANAGEMENT.py

Comment: I see one big mistake in code - you use many times `Tk` and `mainloop. You should use `Tk` to create only main window. For other windows use `Toplevel`. And program should use only one `mailoop`.

Comment: windows never close automatically - you have to use `welcome.destroy()` to remove window.

Comment: to perform many command - put them in one function and assign this function to button.

Comment: about that using multiple Tk()...it is a group project so everyone was making their windows themselves...the editing of the code still remains. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's a group project or not, tkinter isn't designed to have multiple root windows (you can, but it's an advanced technique that has side effects you probably aren't aware of). Your entire program needs to have exactly one instance of `Tk`.

Comment: well I made Toplevel() but now it is also opening empty tk windows. https://github.com/RohanSreelesh/School_Project_CRM/blob/master/CUSTOMER_MANAGEMENT.py . Can someone help with it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Window never closes automatically when you create new window. You have to use `welcome.destroy()` for this. You can run it in function which creates new window.

```
import tkinter as tk


def welcome_page():
    global welcome

    welcome = tk.Tk()

    tk.Label(welcome, text='Welcome').pack()

    button = tk.Button(welcome, text='OK', command=other_page)
    button.pack()

    welcome.mainloop()


def other_page():
    global welcome
    global other

    welcome.destroy() # close previous window

    other = tk.Tk()

    tk.Label(other, text='Other').pack()

    button = tk.Button(other, text='OK', command=end)
    button.pack()

    welcome.mainloop()


def end():
    global other

    other.destroy() # close previous window


welcome_page()
```

---

Answer (score 0):

To perform the two commands call one command inside the other (sounds like it should be towards the end) and assign the first command to the button.

Answer (score 0):

A button can only call a single function, but that single function can do anything you want.

```
def do_ok():
    print("hello!")
    welcome.destroy()

welcome = Tk()
okbutton = Button(welcome, text='ok', command=do_ok)
okbutton.pack()
welcome.mainloop()
```